# Jon Thornton timepicker will it work with iphone

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone

I've playing around with Thornton's timepicker and while it's great on a desktop or laptop have found the interface on a iphone to be nearly impossible to use.  Has anyone any suggestions on how to make it more user friendly for mobile devices?  here's a fiddle [timepicker](https://jsfiddle.net/rss81/v5nc7npn/5/)

```
<body>
   <form action="iphone_out.php" method="POST">
      <input name="resdate5" type="text" class="time ui-timepicker-input timedrop">
   </form>
</body>



$(document).ready(function() {

$(".timedrop").click(function() {

$(this).timepicker({
  'minTime': '9:00 am',
  'maxTime': '9:00 pm',
  'timeFormat': 'h:i A',
  'disableTextInput': true,
  'disableTouchKeyboard':true,
  'stopScrollPropagation':true
});
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have never used that script, but you instantiate it within a click event handler, that doesn't seem right. Try it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('.timedrop').timepicker({
  'minTime': '9:00 am',
  'maxTime': '9:00 pm',
  'timeFormat': 'h:i A',
  'disableTextInput': true,
  'disableTouchKeyboard':true,
  'stopScrollPropagation':true
});
});
```

Comment: The examples on the demo page (http://jonthornton.github.io/jquery-timepicker/) work well here on iPhone 6

Comment: Rudi, thanks for pointing that out.  Looks like trying to test iphone from js fiddle is might be the problem